# How do I get the time taken to click something in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the value of the time taken to click something and use it elsewhere in the code?

Comment: What do you mean by time to click? Is the time counted since page load?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the time on referrer for the user until he clicked?

You can simply get the timestamp of when the page is loaded and then substract it from the timestamp the button was clicked.

```js
const start = Date.now();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
    document.getElementById('your-id').addEventListener('click', () => 
        const diff = Date.now() - start; // time in ms
    );
);
```